# How to use stack.OrderBy<> in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stack

I want to order a stack of integers in ascending order and found .OrderBy function but don't understand how to use it.

```
Stack<int> integers = new Stack<int>();
integers.OrderBy<integers.Min => integers.Max>;
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: So you want to rearrange the stack so it is in a sorted order? Or just enumerate over it?

Answer (score 3):

`OrderBy` is not a method on `Stack<T>` - it is an *extension method* on `IEnumerable<T>` which `Stack<T>` implements. It does not "re-order" the items within the stack - it *returns* a view into the stack that will enumerate the items in the order that you specify.

If you want to "re-order" the stack (in which case I would question why you have a stack in the first place) you'll need to create a new one:

```
Stack<int> integers = new Stack<int>();
// ..fill the stack..
var sortedInts = integers.OrderBy(i => i);  // enumerate the items in the stack in numerical order
Stack<int> sortedStack = new Stack<int>(sortedInts);  // push the items onto a new stack in numerical order
```

Note that the HIGHEST number will now be at the TOP of the stack (because that's how stacks work...)

Comment: Down-vote: `Stack<T>` does inherit from `IEnumerable<T>`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ataravati:  You don't inherit from interfaces; you _implement_ them like DStanley states in his answer.

Comment: @ataravati that was a typo - check the current answer.

Comment: @AustinSalonen, inherit or implement, that was not the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use `OrderBy` to sort in ascending order and `OrderByDescending` to sort in descending order. Both accept lambda for selecting value that will be used for comparison between items. In your case item itself should be used:

```
IEnumerable<int> sorted = integers.OrderBy(i => i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not reorder the stack. You can reorder the iterator provided by the stack, which won't affect the stack itself. Anyway your syntax should look like this:

```
integers.OrderBy(n => n);
```

Remember that the argument in the '<>' is a generic type. In your case it is an `int` but the int gets filled in automatically by the compiler because it will recognise that `integers` is `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: You might not want to imply that `integers.OrderBy(n => n);` by itself actually does something...

Comment: if you want to say that you have to add something like `var sortedIntegers = intergers.OrderBy(n => n);`, I totally agree with you. It might is not as self explaining as I thought.